# clone <select> and add remove button

Tags: jquery, html, smarty

In my template file I have something similar to this :

```
<select name="author[]">
{section name="something" loop=$something} 
<option value="{$something[something].name}">{$something[something].name}</option>
{/section}
</select>
```

what I want is to create a button that adds another `select` element displaying the same `options` of my first `select` element. How can I do that using jQuery?

this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/) does the same concept that I want. but adds a text input not a select input. also, it does not add any values from the first input.

What I want is a button that copies my select code and display it again with all its options and adds a remove button for each extra select element just like the example that I have provided.

**[Edit]**

Now I know that I can use `clone` to copy elements. But, I cannot seem to find a way to add a remove button for each element that I clone. How can that be done?

**[Edit2]**

This [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfFLt/158/) does the job of adding the remove button. However, I do not want the remove button to be displayed on my original `select` element

**[Edit3]**

I have manged to get what I wanted by using CSS to hide the remove button from the first `select` element see this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tfFLt/286/). Nevertheless, I would like to see it executed by only using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's API features [*powerful selectors*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), which you can (and should) make use of:

Focusing on IDs alone complicates your code when you're dealing with dynamic DOM manipulations (which is the rule) - the recommendation is to use class selectors instead.
Your code can be as simple as:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".add").click(function() {
        $("#select").clone()
            .removeAttr("id")
            .append( $('<a class="delete" href="#">Remove</a>') )
            .appendTo("#additionalselects");
    });
    $("body").on('click',".delete", function() {
        $(this).closest(".input").remove();
    });
});
```

Here's a [**link to jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/gGSxa/4/)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [jquery clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Something like this:

```
$('[name="author[]"]').clone().appendTo('#your_div_id_where_you_want_it');
```

You might want to give your select box an id to make selecting and cloning it look more clean. Also the `[]` in the name attribute may cause an issue so making an id would solve that too. The select would look like this if you want to add the id:

```
<select id="author" name="author[]">
```

And then the clone line would look like this:

```
  $('#author').clone().appendTo('#your_div_id_where_you_want_it');
```

Comment: you might want .first().clone(), not sure what happens after you've cloned a single time whether clone will clone all objects that you grab on subsequent calls.

Comment: @nathanhayfield that would just move the element that you've saved as a variable leaving it only in the latest position that you put it. You need to clone() the saved element, e.g. `$myselect=$('[name="author[]"]').clone(); $myselect.clone().appendTo(...);`

Comment: How can I add extra HTML to my code? for example, a remove button that deletes a cloned input.